# socket.io how to emit a hot event for every new connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a client as a standalone application and a server.

Server:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log(socket.id);
  socket.emit('stakes', {hello: 'world'});
});
```

Client:

```
socket.on('stakes', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Current behaviour:

- Server logs socket.id after every client refresh (new socket connection)
- **Client logs data only after server restart**

Expected behaviour:

- Server logs socket.id after every client refresh (new socket connection)
- **Client logs data after EVERY CLIENT REFRESH.**

Answer (score 0):

Use `io.sockets.emit` fuction to emit to all connected sockets.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log(socket.id);
  io.sockets.emit('stakes', {hello: 'world'});
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to emit event from the server to every client connected.

Comment: Still the same. The event is emitted only when I restart the server. Refreshing a client logs socket.id but doesn't emit the event.